# Text beneath image going out of circular div

Tags: html, css, django

I have a circular div which I made by applying some css styling like border-radius. Within the div, it contains an icon and below the icon, the corresponding text. However, the image is getting displayed properly, but the text is going out of the div. There is much vertical space between the icon and the text.

How do I solve this?

Here is my code:

```
    .internship_cat{
        object-fit: contain;
        background-color: #06314e;; 
        margin-top: 5px;
        margin-bottom: 10px; 
        margin-left:10px; 
        border-radius: 50px;
        transition: transform 450ms;
        width: 110px;
        height: 110px;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;


    }

    .internship_cat:hover{
        transform: scale(1.08);
    }

</style>


<div class="internship_categories" style="margin-top:10px; display:flex; overflow-x:scroll; 
overflow-y:hidden" >
   {% for ind_type in industry_type %}
      <div class="internship_cat">
           <img src="{{ ind_type.picture_icon.url }}" alt="" width="100" height="100">
              <span class="caption" style="color: white; ">{{ind_type.industry_name}}</span>
      </div>
  {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Could you make a working snippet? Preferably just CSS and HTML - it's impossible to tell from what you have shown so far exactly what the problem is as we don't know some of the CSS (like caption) or how much text is in the industry name. Just at a glance, your image is taking up exactly your div space (100x100), does class caption compensate for that?